# MongoDB .NET how to remove item from embedded array

Tags: .net, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

Given the collection

```
{
    "_id" : 137,
    "name" : "Tamika Schildgen",
    "scores" : [
        {
            "type" : "exam",
            "score" : 4.433956226109692
        },
        {
            "type" : "homework",
            "score" : 65.50313785402548
        },
        {
            "type" : "homework",
            "score" : 89.5950384993947
        }
    ]
};
```

How can I remove the score with lowest value of score.type ="homeowrk" from the scores embeded array with  in collection? Have tried with below code but no luck, unable to find where its going wrong.

```
var col = db.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("students");
            var pipeline = new BsonDocument[] {
                           new BsonDocument{{"$unwind", "$scores"}},
                           new BsonDocument{ {"$match",new BsonDocument { { 
    "scores.type", "homework" } } } },
                           new BsonDocument{{"$group", new BsonDocument{
                                            {"_id", "$_id"},
                                            {"lowscore",new BsonDocument{
                                            {"$min","$scores.score"}}
                            }}
                        }}
                      };
var result = await col.Aggregate<BsonDocument>(pipeline).ToListAsync();
```

Here I am getting the right results, low score of type homework but the below update is not removing item from the collection and I can't figure it out out.

```
foreach (var doc in result)
{

    var filterS = new BsonDocument("_id", doc.GetElement("_id").Value.ToInt32());
    var update = Builders<BsonDocument>.Update.PullFilter("scores",
        Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("scores.score", doc.GetElement("lowscore").Value.ToDecimal128()));
    var mresult = col.FindOneAndUpdateAsync(filterS, update).Result;
    Console.WriteLine(mresult);

}
```

Comment: Have tried but this hasnt updated anything..I had same query to return all scores for type home work where score is lowest but I was unable to remove that item from array. db.students.aggregate([{$unwind:"$scores"},{$match:{"scores.type":"homework"}},{$sort:{"scores.score":1}}]).pretty();

Comment: I resolved this by using couple of for each loops and dic. Dictionary<int, BsonValue> dic = new Dictionary<int, BsonValue>(); Add lowest score item to this dictonary and another for each to loop through dictonary and remove from mongodb collection.